# Can we have React 16 Portal functionality React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `React Native` which ships with `React 16` alpha release which supports [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). While in browser and having access to DOM we can use id or classes to access element from anywhere in component/file hierarchy like this:

```
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');
```

and pass it to `createPortal(child, container)` container arg. [React docs clearly says](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) than container should be DOM element:

> The second argument (container) is a DOM element.

This function is also a method of `ReactDOM` which doesn't exist in React Native.

Is there a way to achieve the similar functionality in React Native?

### Use case:

I want to render an animated overlay in the root of my application but pass the Animated values props to it from a parent deep in the tree hierarchy (can't use Redux actions for such things).

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem where I wanted to render overlay on top of everything from deeply nested child component. I solved my problem with React Native's [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html)

It renders its content on top of everything :) Easy to use and no need for extra dependencies

Comment: That's the best answer!

Comment: But.. a Modal is only for popups. Sometimes you need to interact with the screen and have an absolutely positioned element outside of its parent's bounds

Answer (score 7):

I don't think `react-native` provides this functionality in its own API.
 But there is a library available which provides the similar functionality. [react-gateway](https://github.com/cloudflare/react-gateway)

As per the docs of `react-gateway`,

> It also works in universal (isomorphic) React applications without any additional setup and in React Native applications.
>
> React Gateway does not directly depend on react-dom, so it works fine with React Native under one condition:
>
> **You must pass React Native component like View or similar to component prop of .**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {
  Gateway,
  GatewayDest,
  GatewayProvider
} from 'react-gateway';

export default class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GatewayProvider>
        <View>
          <Text>React Gateway Native Example</Text>
          <View>
            <Gateway into="one">
              <Text>Text rendered elsewhere</Text>
            </Gateway>
          </View>
          <GatewayDest name="one" component={View} />
        </View>
      </GatewayProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

The above example is taken from the repo itself. [react native example](https://github.com/cloudflare/react-gateway#react-native-example)

Comment: I though there's a native way for it using `onLayout` of `View`. But now I'm looking into `react-gateway` and `react-native-portal` that use Provider and even emitters.

Comment: I'm not much aware of `react-native` API so I might be mistaken. :) There is also another library [react-portal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-portal) available similar to `react-gateway`. If you are interested. :)

Comment: seems like `react-portal` works on React since it needs DOM but the other 2 works on react-native too.

Comment: Okay. Good to know it. Thanks :) I'm updating my answer to reflect it so that it can help others in future for reference :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I've updated the answer with example and essential information from the repo :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to render the items above the screen can be done using `react-native-paper` library.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Portal } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Portal.Host>
    <Text>Content of the app</Text>
  </Portal.Host>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

Portal host renders all of its children Portal elements. For example, you can wrap a screen in Portal.Host to render items above the screen.

Here is the link which describes its usage:
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/portal-host.html